# storing radio button value and presetting after refresh- cgi visiblity issue

Tags: perl, radio-button, save

I have a html table that has 2 radio buttons for every row and a save button. I want to store the value of the radio button when saved and preset the value when the page is revisited.This is the html code I have written

```
<form action='table_extract.cgi' method = 'get'>
        <td><input type='radio' name='signoff' value = 'approve'>Approve<br>
        <input type='radio' name='signoff' value='review'>Review</td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='button' value='Save'/></td></form>
```

This is what is in table_extract.cgi

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use warnings;
print <<END;
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
END

my $regfile = 'signoff.out';
my $sign;
$sign = param('signoff');

open(REG,">>$regfile") or fail();
print REG "$sign\n";
close(REG);
print "param value :", param('signoff');
print <<END;
<title>Thank you!</title>
<h1>Thank you!</h1>
<p>signoff preference:$sign </p>
END

sub fail {
   print "<title>Error</title>",
   "<p>Error: cannot record your registration!</p>";
  exit; }
```

This is just first part of the problem. I was not able to find any output in console or in poll.out. Once I read the values, I need to preset the values to the radio buttons that was saved by the user in the previous visit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the HTML, your submit button has two `type` attributes. When I repaired this, the form worked for me.

You are doing too much work to save the form. See chapter [SAVING THE STATE OF THE SCRIPT TO A FILE](http://p3rl.org/CGI#SAVING-THE-STATE-OF-THE-SCRIPT-TO-A-FILE) in the documentation.

Comment: thanks. I figured out the two types in the submit button. I figured out the problem. The issue was the form does not send the params to the .cgi script in the form action. I searched and found out that I need to make the .cgi file visible to apache. I tried various ways as suggested. The connection is not made between the html file and the .cgi file. Please do suggest along those lines.

Comment: No, that's off topic for this site. Go to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) for that kind of problems instead.

Comment: I posted this in server fault, they migrated it here.